# How to switch the Product Tax Class based on VAT ID Number

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, tax-class

For all my products I have a set a tax class with 19%.

The request:
If a customer put in a valid VAT ID Number within the checkout process - **certain** products should be calculated based on a tax class with 0%. Without a VAT ID Number all products must be calculated with 19% tax.

if no VAT ID exists:

product a: 19% 
product b: 19% 
product c: 19%

if VAT ID exists:

product a: 19% 
 product b: 19% 
 product c: 0%

Is this possible?